# SharePoint Hiding fields in newform, dispform, editform

Tags: sharepoint, hide

I have a task here when I need some assistance. what I am trying to accomplish is the follow..

1. Hide some fields on the newform, editform and dispform with in SharePoint (2013)
2. The field I am trying to hide is ONLY the input/textbox field not the whole column/heading associated with it. Basically I have a form with a heading and an associated textbox(single line of text) next to it, what I would like to do is hide the textbox only.

I have used the F12 IE tools to select the text box to which displays the following souce code:

```
<input title="Travel" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" id="Travel_f6801fb9-c4ff-4109-acb9-f7dd63c1d98a_$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" value="">
```

(the textbox is associated with my "Travel" column)

Now when I use the F12 tools while selecting this, I added some css(from that I can tell) under the "inline Style" top heading which was "display=none" and bingo it works!.

Now what I cant do here is add this to the forms permanently. I have tried to google this by adding a Content web part to the form and try some CSS/Java script but I simply do not have the skills in this area.. does this make sense?

examples: [image: with field]

[image: without field]

any help would be great

Cheers!

Comment: Chad you have two options. 1. Create custom new/edit item form add css for hiding textbox there. 2. If you are using custom masterpage in your masterpage code add css for hiding textbox or best practice is to add it in css file referenced in the masterpage.

Comment: Is this an already existing list/library or do you have access to the solution with the list definition? If so, you can configure each field of the list in Visual Studio, and you can set properties, in which forms the field should appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 was introduced `Client Side Rendering` (aka `CSR`) which is used for rendering list views, list forms and search results. For a more details follow [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms) article.

The following *JavaScript template* demonstrates how to hide field controls in List Form pages:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      OnPostRender: hideFieldControls
    });

});



function getFieldControlId(field){
   return field.Name + '_' + field.Id + '_$' + field.Type + 'Field';
}

function hideFieldControl(field){
   var fieldControlId = getFieldControlId(field);
   var fieldControl = document.getElementById(fieldControlId);
   fieldControl.style.display = "none";
}


function hideFieldControls(ctx){
    var fieldNamesToHide = ['JobTitle','WorkPhone'];  //<- set field names to hide here
    if(fieldNamesToHide.indexOf(ctx.ListSchema.Field[0].Name) > -1) {
        hideFieldControl(ctx.ListSchema.Field[0]);
    }
}
```

### How to apply changes

- Open List Form page in *edit mode*
- Add `Script Editor` web part on the page
- Insert the specified JavaScript template by enclosing it using
  `script` tag Note: specify field names to hide via `fieldNamesToHide` variable
- Save page

### Results

Pic 1. Original New Form page

[image]

Pic. 2 Customized New Form (field controls for `Job Title` and `Business Phone` are hidden)
[image]